# Obstructions to symplectically embedding compact manifolds of dimension $4$ or higher

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, sg.symplectic-geometry, cohomology, homology, embeddings

It is known in Li's paper (http://arxiv.org/pdf/0812.4929v1.pdf) that in compact symplectic manifolds $(X^{2n},\omega)$ of dimension at least $2n\geq 4$, an immersed symplectic surface represents a $2$-homology class as long as that homology class has positive symplectic area.  When $2n\geq 6$, this immersion may even be taken to be an embedding.

My question regards finding symplectically embedded submanifolds $(M^{2d},\sigma)$ which are *themselves* of dimension $2d\geq 4$.  Does anybody here know of any progress on this front?  I have not found it yet, and I'm not optimistic that it exists in great abundance, if at all.

Comment: Obstructions for $(M^4,\sigma)\hookrightarrow(X^4,\omega)$ are highly studied, using the notion of "capacities".

Comment: @ChrisGerig Thank you, Chris.  I'm aware of this already.  You don't happen to know about $(M^{4},\sigma)\hookrightarrow (X^{2n},\omega)$ for $2n\geq 6$ arbitrary, do you?